# <input> with display:block inside a text-align:center div

Tags: html, css

With this:

```
<div id="parentdiv" style="text-align:center;width:600px;margin:auto;">
  <input type="button" value="push me" />
</div>
```

The button is aligned to the center of the browser window (as desired) in FF, Chrome, IE7 and IE8.

But, add "display:block" to the button:

```
<div id="parentdiv" style="text-align:center;width:600px;margin:auto;">
  <input type="button" style="display:block;" value="push me" />
</div>
```

The button is aligned to the center in IE7 - and is **not aligned to the center** in FF, Chrome and IE8.

Why? And can a button (or any <input>) with display:block be center-aligned in some way? (other than using <center> - which works on all browsers mentioned, btw - but is "forbidden"...)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This way it can work:

```
<input type="button" style="width:100px;margin:0 auto;display:block;" value="push me" />
```

To force a block input (originally display:inline element) to be centered, you have to set a fixed width and then the margin to 0 auto ;)

Answer (score 1):

from the [css standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-css3-text-20101005/#text-align):

> This property describes how inline contents of a block are horizontally aligned

so when your elements (no matter what they are, divs, spans, inputs, etc.) are inline, text-align has an affect on them, and when theyre display:block, by standard definition, text-align will not align them

you can fix this by setting margin:0 auto and fixing a width, like steweb suggested, or alternatively (depending on your specific requirements):

```
<input type="button" style="display:inline-block;" value="push me" />
```

Comment: I can't' test it in IE right now on my mac.. but I don't remember if it works on IE<8.. Am I wrong?

Comment: @steweb, i dont really care if it works in ie6, and it should work in ie7. not sure though.

Comment: I don't care too about ie6 :) ..if it doesn't work in IE7 could be a "problem" coz unfortunately lots of people are still using it

Comment: @MSS, http://jsfiddle.net/QN2qu/, works with ie9 and chrome. Before you downvote and make useless comments check with a proper example, and provide evidence of any claim you make.

Answer (score 0):

Elements that are displayed as [blocks are centred with auto margins](http://dorward.me.uk/www/centre/#block). The `text-align` property should only centre [inline children](http://dorward.me.uk/www/centre/#inline). Internet Explorer has bugs surrounding this.